# Django abstract alphabet validator

Tags: django, django-validation

I'm writing a field that takes an alphabet as an argument and generates a crypto-secure random string from that alphabet. The validator also takes a length argument. Here's the template for that:

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

class AlphabetValidator(RegexValidator):

    def __init__(self, alphabet, max_length):
        pass
```

As you can see, the idea is to use `RegexValidator` as a base class. The problem lies within the flexibility that is given to the alphabet, as it can incorporate everything. I'm only using it for validating either letters and digits or only hexadecimal representations, but I'd like to make it safe for other uses as well in advance.

Also notice that any characters from the given alphabet should be taken literally, including `$`, `.`, and so on. What I have in mind is to wrap the alphabet in a class: `"[" + alphabet "]"`. This, of course, implies that I need to escape `-` and `]`. I'm not sure about `[`.

My question is whether escaping these three characters would be enough? Are there others I should consider? Or whether the community has a better way to suggest to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself, found [re.escape()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape):

> Escape special characters in pattern. This is useful if you want to
>   match an arbitrary literal string that may have regular expression
>   metacharacters in it.

Here's what I ended up with:

```
self._alphabet = '^(%s){%d}$' % (re.escape(alphabet), max_length)
```